# change tab icon in different React Route

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

One way to change the default react icon for Home page ("/") is to update `index.html`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
// here
    <link rel="icon" href="./logo.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
```

in the public folder or `manifest.json`.

```
"icons": [
    {
// here
      "src": "logo.png",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
```

But how do we also update the icon for different route, for example, ("/profile/:id")? It seems that these updates don't work on route pages.